# What types of audio are supported by Cloud Speech API?

Tags: google-cloud-speech

There are a lot of audio formats (e.g., mp3, m4a), sources (e.g., dictation, commands, phone calls, meetings) and devices (e.g., phones, PCs, IoT devices). Which ones work best with Cloud Speech API?

Answer (score 4):

> Which ones work best with Cloud Speech API?

Supported ones shall work best:

- LINEAR16 Uncompressed 16-bit signed little-endian samples. This is
  the only encoding that may be used by speech.asyncrecognize.
- FLAC This is the recommended encoding for speech.syncrecognize and
  StreamingRecognize because it uses lossless compression; therefore
  recognition accuracy is not compromised by a lossy codec.
- MULAW    8-bit samples that compand 14-bit audio samples using G.711 PCMU/mu-law.
- AMR  Adaptive Multi-Rate Narrowband codec. sampleRate must be 8000 Hz.
- AMR_WB   Adaptive Multi-Rate Wideband codec. sampleRate must be 16000
  Hz.

https://cloud.google.com/speech/reference/rest/v1beta1/RecognitionConfig#AudioEncoding