# What audio file types does Google Cloud Speech API recognize?

Tags: audio, google-cloud-platform, google-speech-api, google-voice-search

I'm trying to use Google's Cloud Speech API. There's documentation and code examples here:

```
https://cloud.google.com/speech/docs/basics
https://cloud.google.com/speech/docs/rest-tutorial
```

I can get the sample code to run just fine if I point it to an included file, audio.raw, but not with a brief .wav file.

I have no idea what format the audio sample file is:

```
$ file audio.raw 
audio.raw: data
```

With my .wav file that has maybe 10 seconds of audio I get an empty result.

I'm aware of this answer.

[google cloud speech api returning empty result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39712623/google-cloud-speech-api-returning-empty-result)

My question was asked before but there was not an answer to the question.

[What types of audio are supported by Cloud Speech API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38485515/what-types-of-audio-are-supported-by-cloud-speech-api)

I can't imagine that I would have to get the properties of the audio file just right to get this to work. I assume a common use case, mine, is that someone records a meeting, has no idea of the parameters of the recording and just wants a text file.

Comment: @alex I see you responded to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39712623/google-cloud-speech-api-returning-empty-result. Any thoughts on my question?

Comment: You cannot message other uses on SO (@foo does not work that way here)

Comment: Good to know. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**EDIT May 2020: seems things improved and this answer is no longer correct: [see new docs](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/encoding) for details about supported formats (including WAV).**

---

As of 2016 the `WAV`e format does not seem to be supported. These formats are documented as supported though:

- LINEAR16 Uncompressed 16-bit signed little-endian samples. This is
  the only encoding that may be used by speech.asyncrecognize.
- FLAC This is the recommended encoding for speech.syncrecognize and
  StreamingRecognize because it uses lossless compression; therefore
  recognition accuracy is not compromised by a lossy codec. Only 16-bit samples are supported. Not all fields in STREAMINFO are supported
- MULAW    8-bit samples that compand 14-bit audio samples using G.711 PCMU/mu-law.
- AMR  Adaptive Multi-Rate Narrowband codec. sampleRate must be 8000 Hz.
- AMR_WB   Adaptive Multi-Rate Wideband codec. sampleRate must be 16000
  Hz.

https://cloud.google.com/speech/reference/rest/v1beta1/RecognitionConfig#AudioEncoding

Comment: Thanks. That got me past that problem. I installed sox and converted the .wav file to .flac. Now I get a different problem which I'll research and post about separately.

Comment: as for flac: `Only 16-bit samples are supported. Not all fields in STREAMINFO are supported.`. Checks docs

Answer (score 1):

According to Google Cloud Speech Documentation : 
Speech-to-Text supports WAV files with LINEAR16 or MULAW encoded audio.
https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/encoding